# Select rows based on information stored in separate table

Tags: mysql, sql, wikimedia, wikimedia-dumps

First of all I'm sorry for the overly vague title, however I'm unfamiliar with the proper terminology for a problem like this.

I'm attempting to retrieve a list of page titles from Wiktionary (Wikimedia wiki-based dictionary) where the page must be categorized under `English_lemmas`, but must *not* be categorized under `English_phrases`, `English_slang`, and `English_%_forms` (where % is the wildcard).

The two necessary tables are `page` which contains page information (`page_id`, `page_title`), and `categorylinks` which contains the categories that each page is categorized under.

The relevant structure of [`page`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table) is like so:

```
+---------+------------------+
| page_id | page_title       |
+---------+------------------+
| 0       | race             |
| 1       | racing           |
| 2       | that's all folks |
| 3       | fire             |
| 4       | psychédélique    |
+---------+------------------+
```

and the relevant structure of [`categorylinks`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Categorylinks_table) is like so: (I've added line breaks for easier reading)

```
+---------+-------------------------+
| cl_from | cl_to                   |
+---------+-------------------------+
| 0       | English_lemmas          |
| 0       | English_verbs           |

| 1       | English_lemmas          |
| 1       | English_verbs           |
| 1       | English_non-lemma_forms |

| 2       | English_lemmas          |
| 2       | English_phrases         |

| 3       | English_lemmas          |
| 3       | English_nouns           |

| 4       | French_lemmas           |
| 4       | French_adjectives       |
+---------+-------------------------+
```

where `categorylinks.cl_from` is a direct reference to `page.page_id` and `categorylinks.cl_to` is the title of the category.

I need to select `race` and `fire` as they are both categorized under `English_lemmas`, but *not* `racing` or `that's all folks` as in addition to both being categorized under `English_lemmas` they are also categorized under `English_%_forms` and `English_phrases` respectively, and not `psychédélique` as it is not categorized under `English_lemmas`.

Therefore the ideal result would be

```
+---------+------------------+
| page_id | page_title       |
+---------+------------------+
| 0       | race             |
| 3       | fire             |
+---------+------------------+
```

Is this something that is feasible to achieve efficiently? And if so how can I achieve this?

I have a fairly basic understanding of SQL (basic SELECT, UPDATE, etc statements), so something like this is far beyond my comprehension.

Comment: For some perspective: `categorylinks` contains 21,868,252 rows, 494,550 of which are `WHERE cl_to='English_lemmas'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your requirements correctly:

```
select *
  from page
  where page_id not in (select cl_from from categorylinks
                         where cl_to like 'English_%_forms'
                            or cl_to like 'English_phrases')
    and page_id in (select cl_from from categorylinks
                      where cl_to like 'English_lemmas')
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify that there needs to be a row where `cl_to = 'English_lemmas'` for the page? as otherwise it will select pages from different languages that are categorized under, say, `French_lemmas`. I should have expanded on that in the example.

Comment: I think my corrected and updated answer should do what you want.

Comment: Not only is it perfect but it seems to work well on the large table sizes. Thank you very much!

Comment: You only really need two selects: `SELECT page.* FROM page JOIN categorylinks ON page_id = cl_from WHERE cl_to = 'English_lemmas' AND page_id NOT IN (SELECT cl_from FROM categorylinks WHERE cl_to like 'English_%_forms' OR cl_to LIKE 'English_phrases');`. Maybe the query optimizer can figure that out but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: You're right.  I think it would run a bit faster too.